# WebDriver update failing

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, webdriver

I am trying to install Protractor and I am currently stuck at updating web driver.

I am running Node 8.9.4 and npm version is 5.6.0.

When I run the following command

```
webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl
```

I get the following exception.

```
[18:10:35] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[18:10:35] I/config_source - curl -ok ...\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\standalone-response.xml https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/
[18:10:35] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[18:10:35] I/config_source - curl -ok ...\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chrome-response.xml https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/
[18:10:35] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[18:10:35] I/config_source - curl -ok ...\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\gecko-response.json https://api.github.com/repos/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
(node:19392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'ListBucketResult' of undefined
(node:19392) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[18:10:35] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[18:10:35] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[18:10:36] I/downloader - curl -ok ...\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
[18:10:36] I/downloader - curl -ok ...\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.141/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
[18:10:36] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[18:10:37] I/downloader - curl -ok ...\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium/geckodriver-v0.24.0.zip https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-win32.zip
[18:10:37] I/update - geckodriver: unzipping geckodriver-v0.24.0.zip

...\node_modules\adm-zip\zipFile.js:66
                        throw Utils.Errors.INVALID_FORMAT;
                        ^
Invalid or unsupported zip format. No END header found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rdx-app@0.0.0 webdriver: `webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.38 --ignore_ssl`
```

Comment: execute `webdriver-manager clean` first to remove all downloaded driver files in case any incomplete driver file created in previous update, then execute `webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl`

Comment: @yong - tried cleaning before update but result was still the same.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigaion I found out what may be the problem.
In adm-zip there already is raised ticket for this bug: https://github.com/cthackers/adm-zip/issues/99

Over there you have a discussion regarding to your problem:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1005

Comment: I am behind a corporate proxy and seems like the packages are blocked.

Comment: specify proxy in update command `webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl --proxy <your corporate proxy address>`